# Removing the last digits in string

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834
```

I want to remove the digits at the end of the string, basically the 16 digits at the end of the string. In the end it should look like this:

```
[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)
```

This is my code that I have written so far

```
var str="[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834";
var n=str.substr(1,74);
document.write(n);
```

The problem is the string will be different so each will have different amount of characters. So how I remove the digits at the end of the string in javascript?

Comment: You want to remove this "_20121104_032834"

OR

"_032834"

Comment: @ameyarote: The OP states "16 digits" in the example, so it would be the former. (But the length is not fixed, as stated in the last sentence.)

Comment: @w3d: Ok..! please check the answer which I suggeted below it exactly removes all the last numbers.(Please check and tell if any diffent thing is required)

Answer (score 7):

If it is always exactly 16 digits in the end of the string then:

```
s = s.substr(0, s.length - 16);
```

Otherwise you can use regexp:

```
s = s.replace(/[_0-9]+$/, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `substr`, use `replace` and a regular expression:

```
str.replace(/_\d{8}_\d{6}/,'')
```

Running demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7BpLU/).

References at MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Although this isn't necessarily "at the end of the string". You will need an anchor `$` to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Using `slice` you can use negative indexes.

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/A5UaJ/2/

```
var str="[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834";
alert(str.slice(0, -16))​
```

Comment: But according to the OP, the length of the string to be removed varies.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I thought the OP meant the prefixed string was the variable length string. @ADC's suggestion would be better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

just change your code to calculate the index according to the string length the following code should do the trick.

```
myString.substr(0, myString.length - 16);
```

Comment: Although the OP states, "will have different amount of characters" - so it's not always 16 chars that need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of solutions:

```
var str="[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834";

// Solution 1
// Ugly, since you don't know the number of characters
var n = str.substr(0, 75); // Take note these variables are different than yours!
document.write(n);
document.write("<br />");

// Solution 2
// Only works when the string itself contains no underscores
var n2 = str.split("_")[0];
document.write(n2);
document.write("<br />");

// Solution 3
// Only works if the last amount of numbers are always the same
var n3 = reverse(str);
n3 = n3.substr(16, n3.length);
n3 = reverse(n3);
document.write(n3);

function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}​
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6WVA/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str="[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834";
var find=str.indexOf('_');
find=find-1;
var n=str.substr(1,find);
document.write(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this function

Check Example - http://jsfiddle.net/QN68Q/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body onload="check();"> 

<script>
function check()
{
var theImg= "[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834";

var x = theImg.split("_");
alert(""+x[0]);
}
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

it remove last numbers , is this what you required ?