# How do i return a number excluding the last digit?

Tags: javascript

So I have a number like 5467. I want my code to return 546.

I tried taking the last number and subtracting it from the original number but I get 5460 instead of 546.

Comment: convert it to string and do substring. :)

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Combine `/` with `%`:

```
(5467 - (5467 % 10)) / 10
```

> 546

Comment: You have a typo in your result 564. Its 546.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you also need to divide my 10. You could do something like this:

```
var number = 5467;
number = number - (number % 10); // This will subtract off the last digit.
number = number / 10;
console.log(number); // 546
```

We first use the modulo operator `%` to get the last digit, and we subtract it from `number`. That reduces the number from 5467 to 5460. Now to chop off the last digit (which is guaranteed to be a 0) we divide by 10 and get 546.

Written more concisely you could do:

```
number = (number - ( number % 10)) / 10;
```

Comment: it works now i wanna repeat the process until my answer is less than 30. How do i do that with a while loop

Comment: Just do `while(number >= 30) { number = (number - ( number % 10)) / 10; }`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can do the most concise being:

```
Math.floor(num / 10);
```

Or, convert to a string, remove the last character and convert back to number.

```
parseInt(num.toString().slice(0, -1));
```

Comment: The first can be reduced to `num/10|0`, which works with strings and numbers.

Comment: also `~~(num/10);` :)

Comment: But that's two more characters!! You'll kill the interwebs!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If string representation would be fine for you then one other way is

```
var num = 5467,
    cut = (num/10).toFixed(); // <-'547'
```

Well... warning..! i have to say `toFixed()` method rounds if necessary. So in this particular example it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont mind some of the other answers, but i feel that this maybe too fixed on it being a number.

Which it is, but you want to remove the last digit/char, regardless of the number, so why not substr?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

```
var s = 5467;
s = s.toString().substr(0, s.toString().length - 1);
console.log(s)
```

or even easier:

```
var s = (5467).toString();
s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
console.log(s)
```

These dont take into account single digit numbers, so passing in 1 would return blank. To answer that you could simply do a check like:

```
var s = (1).toString();
if(s.length > 1)
  s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
console.log(s)
```

---

Also, similar question to:

[Remove last digits from an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123976/remove-last-digits-from-an-int)

[Remove the last digits of a number (not string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649511/remove-the-last-digits-of-a-number-not-string)

[Removing the last digits in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563895/removing-the-last-digits-in-string)

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, the information there is generally poor. Use ECMA-262 or MDN.

Answer (score 0):

To truncate digits from the right hand side until the number is less than 30, keep dividing by 10 and rounding down until a suitable value is reached:

```js
var n = 12341235;

while (n > 30) n = n/10|0;

document.write(n);
```

The greater than and division operations will coerce *n* to a number, so it can be a number or string. If [`ToNumber(n)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber) results in *NaN* (e.g. `n = 'foo'`), then the value of *n* is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide the number by 10 and `parseInt()`

```
var num = 5467;
num = parseInt(num/10);
```

Update :

To repeat the process until the answer is less than 30, use `while` loop as

```js
var num = 5467;

while(num >= 30) {
  num = parseInt(num/10);
}

document.write(num);
```